# For a long running program, is it preferable to store data in memory or in a file cache?

Tags: perl, caching, optimization, dictionary

I have a perl script that is continuously monitoring various directories for new files. To accomplish this, it runs forever in a `while(1)` block with a `sleep` command at the end. Currently, I am storing identifying information in a hash that maps the directory to a unique identifier. When a new file is placed into the directory, that identifier is incremented so I can see there is a new file whenever the greatest identifier is larger than the mapped value. This works well, but now I am wondering if it would be possible to optimize my code since it will be running 24/7.

I have previously used `File::Cache` with perl to store data in a file rather than in memory. **Would using file caching be a better solution rather than storing the (relatively small) hashmap in memory?**

Comment: What happens if your process dies for some reason? If you don't store the state somewhere more permanent, you could lose a lot of information.

Comment: It's started and monitored by upstart so if it dies unexpectedly it will immediately restart and then it will just store the current state at start up. There is a little bit of a race condition in there but it is negligible for my case.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to optimize?

Comment: Memory usage vs run time/processing power needed. Essentially, I'm looking for what would be a faster choice; what would be a less memory intensive choice; what would require less cycles, etc.

Comment: Depends an awful lot on use case at that point. Trying to optimise if you're just looking at a flag file isn't very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you should use memory:

- it's faster.

Why you should use disk:

- It's bigger.
- It's more persistent.

If your long running process will accumulate data, then you probably want to make sure it's flushed to disk. Otherwise - sooner or later - you'll exhaust main memory, and create knock on impact. (Whilst this can be a problem on disk, it's much less likely).

If your process is just keeping track of a 'marker' to see what you've done so far, then that's not an issue. Stick with a memory based, unless you particularly need to persist the marker across reboots/resets.

I would also suggest having a look at `inotify` instead of a while loop, as that can be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Are you scripts supposed to run on Linux or any other OS providing a kernel subsystem similar to Linux's Inotify? If you are supposed to support only Linux based OS you probably search for [Inotify on metacpan](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Inotify&size=20). Personally I'd take a look at [POEx::Inotify](https://metacpan.org/pod/POEx::Inotify), because POE is really an amazing ecosystem…

Answer (score -2):

so it's not a UNIQUE identifier, it's an incremental variable ... :P

The 2 methods are good it always depend on your needs.

Do you want to keep the count even if there is a reboot ... yes ... file
no ...
memory

It's just my point of view ... and i don't think with that kind of program that you need super fast memory performance ... after all there is a sleep in it ! :P

Have a good day